# Problem with Mergesort in C++

Tags: c++, merge, mergesort

```
vector<int>& mergesort(vector<int> &a) {
    if (a.size() == 1) return a;
    int middle = a.size() / 2;
    vector<int>::const_iterator first = a.begin();
    vector<int>::const_iterator mid = a.begin() + (middle - 1);
    vector<int>::const_iterator last = a.end();
    vector<int> ll(first, mid);
    vector<int> rr(mid, last);

    vector<int> l = mergesort(ll);
    vector<int> r = mergesort(rr);
    vector<int> result;
    result.reserve(a.size());
    int dp = 0, lp = 0, rp = 0;

    while (dp < a.size()) {
        if (lp == l.size()) {
            result[dp] = (r[rp]);
            rp++;
        } else if (rp == r.size()) {
            result[dp] = (l[lp]);
            lp++;
        } else if (l[lp] < r[rp]) {
            result[dp] = (l[lp]);
            lp++;
        } else {
            result[dp] = (r[rp]);
            rp++;
        }
        dp++;
    }
    a = result;
    return a;
}
```

It compiles correctly but while execution, I am getting:

> This application has requested the
>   runtime to end it in an unusual way.

This is a weird error.

**Is there something that is fundamentally wrong with the code?**

Comment: It might help if you mentioned the platform, but the error message sounds a lot like a Visual C++ program that just threw an uncaught exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One problem is with the usage of `reserve()` (either use `resize()` or append items with `push_back()` instead of accessing the index).

---

```
if (a.size() == 1) return a;
int middle = a.size() / 2;
vector<int>::const_iterator first = a.begin();
vector<int>::const_iterator mid = a.begin() + (middle - 1);
vector<int>::const_iterator last = a.end();
vector<int> ll(first, mid);
vector<int> rr(mid, last);
```

This could be another problem. If the size is 2, then `ll` would end up being an empty vector, and this function doesn't appear to handle this. There doesn't seem to be much reason to subtract 1 from middle anyway.

---

It is also possible that you are copying things around far more than needed: you shouldn't need the `l` and `r` vectors (because they will just be copies of `ll` and `rr`), similarly I don't think you need the `result` vector, since you could just write the merged results right back to `a`.

Answer (score 7):

This `result.reserve(a.size())` just affects the vector's ***capacity***, not it's ***size***. (The vector's *capacity* tells up to which *size* the vector can grow without needing to re-allocate and copy all members. Basically it's only there for optimization purposes.) You cannot access any members in `result` after that reservation, since there aren't any.  Either use `result.push_back(...)` instead of `result[dp] = ...` or `result.resize(a.size())` instead of `result.reserve(a.size())`.

I suppose the former could be more effective.

Answer (score 1):

reserve() does not change the amount of contents in the vector.  You've created an empty vector, reserved a certain size for it, and then used v[i] = x;  This is not a valid use of vector since there still isn't any i'th element in the vector.

Use resize() instead.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very unclear, because it is the standard message of VC++ when an exception goes unhandled. You could add a try-catch-clock to your main to get the exception and a more meaningful error:

```
int main() {
    try {
        // do main stuff here
    }
    catch ( std::exception & e ) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This is for the command-line. If your application doesn't have one, use a message box or write the error to a log-file.

With regard to the problem in your code, all the other answers appear to be correct.

Comment: ...or the OP could just run it under the debugger, in which case, it'll probably point to the exact line where it goes bang.